# Como Crear un trigger de auditoria en Oracle (BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE)

Tags: oracle, trigger

Quiero crear un trigger que se ejecute al momento de actualizar eliminar o insertar un registro.
 He probado:

```
 create or replace trigger "ADDRESS_ID_BEFORE_INSERT"
BEFORE
insert or update or delete on "ADDRESS_ID"
    for each row
    DECLARE
    v_usuario nvarchar2(100);
    accion nvarchar2(100);
    v_fecha date;
    begin
        SELECT sysdate INTO v_fecha from dual;
        SELECT user INTO v_usuario FROM dual;

        IF UPDATING THEN 
            INSERT INTO auditoria (ACCION_REALIZADA,FECHA_ACCION,NOMBRE_USUARIO)values('Actualizar',v_fecha,v_usuario);
        ELSEIF DELETING THEN 
            INSERT INTO auditoria (ACCION_REALIZADA,FECHA_ACCION,NOMBRE_USUARIO)values('Elimnar',v_fecha,v_usuario);
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO auditoria (ACCION_REALIZADA,FECHA_ACCION,NOMBRE_USUARIO)values('Insertar',v_fecha,v_usuario);
        END IF; 
    end;
```

Lo que deberia hacer es insertar en otra tabla la accion que el usuario esta haciendo, pero me marca el siguiente error:

> Compilation failed, line 11 (23:45:39) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DELETING" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; Compilation failed, line 16 (23:45:39) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: if

Comment: A mi me parece bien pero no soy experto. Prueba a hacer tres triggers diferentes, por insert/update/delete, a ver si compila. Así no tendrás ifs en el cuerpo del trigger

Comment: por separado si funciona pero tendria 3 trigger

Comment: 1-Los triggers para auditar deben ser en el evento "AFTER".
2-registrar si se hizo el INSERT, or UPDATE or DELETE es insufiente para los análisis de auditoría, hace falta también registrar cuales son los campos y los valores de lo que se insertó o se actualizó o se borró..
3-No se requieren las 2 variables para el usuario y la fecha, puede usar directamente esas funciones en la sentencia INSERT.

Comment: @alvalongo muchas gracias por los concejos, pero en este caso la pregunta es como hacer ese triger en especial y saber porque no funciona de la forma que esta ahora

Comment: El error es que escribió "**ELSEIF**", y lo debe corregir por "**ELSIF**". En lugar de escribir 3 veces el INSERT, mejor asigna a una variable de tipo VARCHAR2 la acción y luego del IF-END IF escribe el INSERT.

Comment: ya probe de esa forma y tambien paso lo mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-En el lenguaje PL/SQL la sentencia **IF** anidada se usa **ELSIF**.
2-Para auditar se debe usar el evento **AFTER** que es cuando ya hay un valor definitivo en cada columna.

Documentación de Oracle sobre [IF THEN ELSIF Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS391)

```
create or replace trigger ADDRESS_ID_audit
after insert or update or delete on "ADDRESS_ID"
for each row
DECLARE
  accion varchar2(20);
begin
  IF UPDATING THEN 
     accion:='actualizar';            
  ELSIF DELETING THEN 
        accion:='borrar';
  ELSE
      accion:='insertar';
  END IF;
  --
  INSERT INTO auditoria 
        (ACCION_REALIZADA,
         FECHA_ACCION,
         NOMBRE_USUARIO
       )
  values(accion,
         sysdate,
         user
        ); 
end ADDRESS_ID_audit;
```

Comment: me da el error `PL/SQL: ORA-00911: invalid characterCompilation failed, line 12 ` que es la lineadonde dice ` accion:='insertar';`

Comment: Yo opino que no es en esa línea y que el problema está en el INSERT, que `...NOMBRE_USUARIO´ )` tiene un apóstrofe al final

Comment: @Alfabravo no no tiene es la coma de arriba, y al compilar dice la linea 12 y el editor dice que la linea 12 es la que menciono

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez Lo siento, pero acabo de crear la tabla auditoría con los campos que se usan aquí (varchar, date, varchar), creé una tabla address_id con un par de campos varchar y corrí el DDL del trigger en esta respuesta y compiló sin problemas. Inserté un registro en address_id y creó el registro en auditoría correctamente. Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta la definición de las tablas involucradas

Comment: cierto, no se que ha pasado pero reinicie , porbe y ha compilado

Comment: Muchas gracias @alvalongo